# Best five card hand

Tags: poker-theory

Me and some friends were playing poker and player 1 had 9/8 and player 2 had 9/3. The flop was K, K, 9, 2, 2. Who would be the winner , please explain.

Comment: You've got the correct idea that its the best 5 card hand. Think about which is your best 5 cards, and your friend's best 5 cards, and i think you can answer this yourself. (hint: you both have 2-pair hands)

Comment: I know we would both have two pair but who would win the pot ? Do you count the pair of 2s or does player 1 win it all ?

Comment: Its the best 5 card hand that wins the pot. If there's a pair of 2s in the best 5 card hand, then it counts. If the pair of 2s is not part of the best 5 card hand, then it does not count. what is player 1's best 5 card hand?

Comment: K-K-9-9-8 defeats K-K-9-9-3.